# How to track task execution statistics using an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, concurrency, statistics, monitoring

I'm firing off tasks using an ExecutorService, dispatching tasks that need to be grouped by task-specific criteria:

```
Task[type=a]
Task[type=b]
Task[type=a]
...
```

Periodically I want to output the average length of time that each task took (grouped by `type`) along with statistical information such as mean/median and standard deviation.

This needs to be pretty fast, of course, and ideally should not cause the various threads to synchronize when they report statistics.  What's a good architecture for doing this?

Comment: I should note; I know _where_ I'll call these methods from, I'd like advice on what I should use to accumulate the data.

Comment: Does each task type have it's own Runnable?

Comment: Yes, they do.  Pretty basic stuff, of course, but there is some information stored in the task before dispatching it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) provides [beforeExecute](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute(java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable)) and [afterExecute](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)) methods that you can override. You could use those to record your statistics in a single (member variable of your ExecutorService) [ConcurrentHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) keyed on some unique identifier for your tasks, and storing the type, start time, and end time.

Calculate the statistics from the `ConcurrentHashMap` when you are ready to look at them.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass [Thread Pool Executor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and track the execution events:

- start on [beforeExecute](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#beforeExecute%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Runnable%29)
- end on [afterExecute](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29)

It's worth noting that the methods are invoked by the worker thread which executes the task, so you need to insure thread safety for the execution tracking code.

Also, the Runnables you will receive will most likely not be your Runnables, but wrapped in FutureTasks.

Comment: Your last point is very important. I had the same question for Callables submitted to a ThreadPoolExecutor. Unfortunately the Runnable that comes into beforeExecute is a FutureTask wrapping my Callable (and it looks like the same thing would be true of a submitted Runnable). As a result, there is no easy way to access your original Runnable/Callable. Disappointing... :(  Looks like I'll be overriding submit() as well to keep a Map from Future to Callable.  I hope it doesn't slow things down too much.

Comment: Surely, it's really worthing nothing even though the docs said it can be used to statistic. But in fact, we cannot check which runnable in the  our situation.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use wrapper/decorator pattern.

```
public class Job implements Runnable {
private Runnable _task;
private Statistics _statistics;

public Job(Runnable task, Statistics statistics) {
    this._task = task;
}

public void run() {
    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    _task.run();
    long e = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long executionTime = e - s;
    _statistics.updateStatistics(executionTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the two other answers are correct, but maybe a bit too complicated (although my answer, while simple, is probably not quite as performant as theirs.

Why not just use Atomic variables to keep track of your stats?  Such as number of tasks run, total execution time (divided by total number, you get avg execution time).  Pass these variables into your Runnable for each task.  Unless your tasks as extremely short lived I do not think the overhead of locking an Atomic variable will impact you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Robert Munteanu. The `beforeExecute` in threadpool really worthing nothing even though the docs said it can be used to statistic. But in fact, we cannot check the runnable's identity in the our situation.

I think a wrapper can arrive this.

```
public interface ICallableHook<V> {
    void beforeExecute(Thread t, Callable<V> callable);
    void afterExecute(Callable<V> callable, V result, Throwable e);
}


private class CallableWrapper<V> implements Callable<V> {
        private ICallableHook hooker;
        private Callable<V> callable;

        CallableWrapper(Callable callable, ICallableHook hooker) {
            this.callable = callable;
            this.hooker = hooker;
        }




    @Override
    public V call() throws Exception {
        if (hooker != null) {
            hooker.beforeExecute(Thread.currentThread(), callable);
        }

        V result = null;
        Exception exception = null;
        try {
            result = callable.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e;
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (hooker != null) {
                hooker.afterExecute(callable, result, exception);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage like this,

```
  for (Callable<XXX> callable : callableList) {
        CallableWrapper<XXX> callableWrapper = new CallableWrapper<>(callable, hooker);
        Future task = completionService.submit(callableWrapper);

    }
```